# Magento2 Catalog price rule randomly stop working

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules

I created a catalog price rule on a 15k catalog; the rule concerns about 10k items.
I often need to re-apply the rule because Magento shows full price.
The rule has a start date and NOT an end date.
Any ideas?

Comment: have you check reindex

Comment: Reindex is working well. When discounts disappears the only way to restore prices is to manually reapply catalog rules.

Comment: you can try to verify indexes sequences in case the correct data is present in the rule index table but this data absent in the price index table it could be the reason. In the general case, the price index should be automatically triggered after rule indexer. By the way, if you are using open source edition, catalog rule runs full indexation by schedule each midnight.

Comment: I add some other tests: 
After rules disappearance I wait more than 24 hours, no automatic reindex at midnight!

Comment: I was thinking to a workaround using a cron that "simulates" my click on apply rules. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is there another price rule that cold take priority over this one?

Comment: No, there's only this rule